# Existe algum sistema de gerenciamento de pacote no Lua?

Tags: lua

Muitas linguagens possuem sistema de gerenciamento de pacotes. Isso facilita muito a vida do programador, tornando o desenvolvimento mais ágil.

Por exemplo, no `Python` temos o `pip` e o `easy_install`, no PHP tempos o `pear` e o `composer`.

- E no `Lua`? Existe algum sistema desse tipo?
- Se sim, quais são os mais utilizados?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O gerenciador de pacotes "padrão" da linguagem é o [LuaRocks](https://luarocks.org/).

[LuaDist](http://luadist.org/) também é usado por alguns, não sei se podemos considerar como gerenciador de pacotes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

Em complemento a resposta do @Maniero

O `LuaRocks` permite que você criar e instalar módulos Lua como pacotes independentes.

Para quem utiliza sistema operacional Linux, a instalação é bem simples.

```
apt-get install luarocks
```

Para instalar um pacote, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
luarocks install json-lua
```